# Does the SVG filter feFlood 'flood-color' property support gradient as input?

Tags: html, svg, svg-filters, radial-gradients, vignette

I am experimenting with SVG filters while trying to create a vignette effect.

I've found a snippet in an old repo where the author did it like this, but `feFlood` doesn't pick up the filter for me. I tried `flood-color="url(#gradient_toaster)"` too but no difference. W3 docs say that this property takes in a color, than was the author may be wrong? If yes, what would be an approach to achieve the vignette effect?

```
<html>
  <svg width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">    
     <defs>      
        <radialGradient id="gradient_toaster">
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#804e0f" stop-opacity="100%" />
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#3b003b" stop-opacity="100%" />
        </radialGradient>

        <filter id="toaster">
          <feFlood flood-color="#gradient_toaster" flood-opacity="0.5" />
          <feBlend mode="screen" in="SourceGraphic" />
        </filter>
     </defs> 

      <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300" filter="url(#toaster)" fill="gray"/>        
  </svg>
</html>
```

Comment: feFlood takes a [colour](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feFloodElement), it does not take a [paint](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#SpecifyingPaint) which is what you're trying to pass it.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks. Wondering, why in this repo, all filter examples use it like that: https://github.com/skrypte/fegram - I was scanning the docs to understand it but of course there is nothing like that. Is there another way to include a gradient into a filter effect?

Comment: Draw a gradient on a shape via fill and apply a filter to the shape too.

Comment: sorry, this doesn't make much sense to me: https://codepen.io/vedtam/pen/XPWYvy?editors=1000#0

Comment: BackgroundImage has poor support in browsers, I think only Edge does it well.

Comment: Many of the filters in that repo are malformed in ways other than the gradient syntax (broken primitive references, out of bounds attributes, using mix-blend-mode as an SVG attribute etc.) Very few, if any, would work as expected.

Comment: @MichaelMullany thanks for taking a look. It was really confusing to see such syntax applied to that amount of work, I was scanning the docs and looking to evidences (while learning in the same time). I gonna fork and fix those filters so others won't have the same experience.

Comment: Hello, I would also like to use the filters from Instagram as SVG filters.
Does anyone know of a current library that uses Instagram filters as
SVG filters only? Currently I have only found the following:
[fegram](https://github.com/skrypte/fegram) -> malformed svg syntax) and [CSSgram](https://una.im/CSSgram/) -> looks nice, but only css. Has anyone ever forked fegram and corrected the malformed svg?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the SVG filter feFlood 'flood-color' property support gradient as input?

No.

I [forked](https://github.com/BuZZ-dEE/SVGram) from a fork of that repository and tried to fix those filters. Please have a look.

> Draw a gradient on a shape via fill and apply a filter to the shape too.

That works for Chromium based browsers, but not in Firefox because of this bug: ["SVG filters `feImage` with `xlink:href` doesn't work with fragments"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=455986).

As a [workaround](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/SVG/Filter/feImage) for Firefox you could try to use it like that:

```
<feImage xlink:href='data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg width="100" height="100"><rect width="50" height="50 /></svg>' /
```

Comment: i tried the same but it is not working even in chrome - 

<feImage
                xlink:href='data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg width="1000" height="1000"><rect width="1000" height="1000" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.86" /></svg>'
              />